# Matlab- how to train and test neural networks with unbalanced data in different folders

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

According to the example of neural networks with matlab, all the data and labels must stay in the same vector. Here is an example from [Matwork's website](http://it.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html)

```
load house_dataset
inputs = houseInputs;
targets = houseTargets;

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

But, what can I do if I have the training and testing data in different .csv files? how can I point how many percent of the training data can be used for the validation?

Also, if the classes of my data are extremely unbalanced (there is one class with much more samples than the other), how the validation split from the training data will be performed? will it balance positive and negative labels for the training and validation?